# A problem of presentation of a matrix product inequality

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra

I have 4 vectors or matrix

```
 aa = {{a[1,1],a[1,2]},{a[2,1],a[2,2]}}
  xx= {x[1],x[2]}
  bb = {b[1],b[2]}
   c = {<=, <=}
```

can I find an operation which gives

```
result= {{a[1,1]x[1]+a[1,2]x[2] <= b[1]},{a[2,1]x[1]+a[2,2]x[2] <= b[2]}}
```

Comment: `Transpose[{LessEqual @@@ Transpose[{aa.xx, bb}]}]`

Comment: `Apply @@@ Transpose@{c, Transpose@{aa.xx, bb}}` where `c = {LessEqual, LessEqual}`.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `Inner[LessEqual, Array[a, {2, 2}].Array[x, 2], Array[b, 2], List]`.